# How can I make Typescript understand that undefined could be a valid value here?

Tags: typescript, lodash, undefined, void

I have a generic function, which is at some point zips a collection of items specified by generic type constraint:

```
import { zip } from 'lodash'

function someFunc<TResult>() {
    // Funciton body omitted
    for (const [result, resolver] of zip(results, resolvers)) {
        if (!resolver) { throw new Error(`long error message`) }
        resolver(result)
    }
}
```

And, unsurprisingly, I get the following error:

> Argument of type 'TResult | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'TResult | PromiseLike'.   Type 'undefined' is not
> assignable to type 'TResult | PromiseLike'.

Which is absolutely logical and helpful in 99% of cases. Usually, I'd just add a check that throws an error if it's undefined, right next to the check for `resolver`.

However, I use this function with `void` parameter type, and `undefined` **is** assignable to `void`. How do I implement a runtime check that handles this case properly?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/m02rqw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I am confused here. In the function body you provided, I don't see any `return` statement, thus the return value should always `undefined` as it is here. It is also completely unclear why your function is using generics (`<TResult>`). I guess the code sample you provided is too unclear to understand what is actually going on here.